# Rails: comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments

I want to comment out something in the application.html.erb

```
 <!--
    <div id="user_nav">
 <% if user_signed_in? %>
   Signed in as <%= current_user.email %>. Not you?
   <%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path %>
 <% else %>
   <%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path %> or
   <%= link_to "Sign in", new_user_session_path %>
<% end %>
</div>

//-->
```

this ist not possible. What is to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `.html.erb` file you can use following code for comment.

```
<!-- Your Comment here -->
```

Comment: That's what the OP already has, and it doesn't stop erb  evaluation.

Answer (score 5):

That's an HTML comment; ERB processing happens on the server side.

```
<%#

%>
```

May work across block-ily, it will certainly work line-by-line.

That said, I'm not sure I'd remove functionality by commenting out the entire section.

Instead consider either (a) using source control, or (b) rendering a partial and commenting *that* out, instead of large chunks of ERB.